# interfacing VGA with Virtex-5 FPGA board

Tags: image-processing, fpga, hdl, virtex

I need to interface VGA screen to Virtex-5 FPGA board in order to display an image. I know how to interface VGA with Spartan-3E starter board. But I have no idea how to do it with Virtex-5.

Comment: If the board has a VGA port, you should be able to interface with it in roughly the same way, just with different pin assignments.

Comment: This board has DVI port in place of VGA port. I guess it just needs a DVI to VGA connector.

Comment: I think it depends on whether the analog pins are connected. I recall there being digital-only versions of DVI where you need to implement different specs.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without more information about the FPGA board in question.  Can you post the schematic of the connection between the DVI port and the FPGA?

Comment: You need to write a new physical layer, which translates VGA signals into signals for the DVI PHY.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the board that you're using, but if you already have experience with VGA on FPGAs I assume that you don't have an VGA connector.

Maybe you can use an external IC to control the signals. Something like ADV7125. You can even get a dev-board for it.